# Websphere ECKeyManager getNextKey randomness

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-commerce

Say that I have a table and I run the following:

```
Long key = ECKeyManager.singleton().getNextKey("my_table");
```

Where

```
LOWERBOUND=100,
UPPERBOUND=999
```

My question is: If I run this two times in sequence, will the returned 'keys' be sequential or 'random' withing the bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the prefetchsize and counter values configured for the table in keys table. The prefetchsize would be the starting value that is retrieved and the next value would be the "prefetchsize+counter" value

More reading on the same:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.database.doc%2Fdatabase%2Fkeys.htm&resultof=%22KEYS%22%20%22kei%22